# When are you allowed to attack?

Tags: legends-of-runeterra

In Runeterra, there's an "attack token" that alternates between players each round and allows you to attack.

If you have the attack token and want to attack that round, do you need to do it as soon as the round begins, or can you play minions and/or spells first, then attack later in the round?

Answer (score 2):

You can atack any time you have your attack token. So playing some units or spells first is possible.

Cards that say "ready your attack" let you gain an attack token, so multiple attacks per round are possible as well.